# MongoDB: Pull complete Key:Array Pair

Tags: mongodb

I have such MongoDB Collection:

```
{
  date: date,
  domain: domain,
  visitors:  [ {owner:owner, ip:ip, views:views} ]
}
```

Now I want to check where date equals date AND domain equals domain it should delete the whole visitors array, e.g.:

```
collection.update({"date":date, {"domain":domain} {"$pull":{"visitors"}} )
```

How to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.test.update({"$and": [{date:"date"}, {domain:"domain"}]}, {"$set":{visitors:[]}})
```

You should use the [`$and` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) to match your update query.

Removing all Elements from the Array is the same as setting the value of visitors to the empty array `[ ]`. But setting it to the empty array is quicker and easier to write and understand, so you should use this.

Comment: The `$and` isn't needed here as multiple query terms are implicitly ANDed already. Just use `{date: date, domain: domain}`.

Comment: yes, but his matching was also wrong and I think it is good to use an `$and` in the first place if you change your query later it is easier to update and understand.

Comment: I have encountered cases where the unnecessary use of `$and` has prevented the query optimizer from using the "right" index, so I've learned to only use it when actually needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could try use the `$set` operator to empty the visitors array instead of removing all items by using the `$pull` operator, which would be much faster as the `$pull` will have to do calculations on arrays:

```
db.collection.update( {"date": date, "domain": domain}, { $set : {"visitors": [] }} , {multi: true} )
```

The equivalent `$pull` operation would be

```
db.collection.update( {"date": date, "domain": domain}, { $pull : { "visitors": {} }}, {multi: true} )
```

Comment: Thanks for added explanation.

Comment: @SirBenBenji No worries, glad you found it useful.

Comment: your `$pull : { "visitors": {} }` does not work for me.