# MongoDB and PyMongo: Upsert multiple values

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to upsert such as this:

```
response = ips.update(
            { "domain":domain }, {"date":date},
            { "$set":{"visitors":visitors, "totalviews":totalViews} }, upsert=True)
```

But I get:

```
TypeError: update() got multiple values for keyword argument 'upsert'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `$and` operator to match your update query:

```
db.test.update({"$and": [{date:"date"}, {domain:"domain"}]}, {"$set":{visitors:[]}})
```

See: [MongoDB: Pull complete Key:Array Pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412073/mongodb-pull-complete-keyarray-pair)

Comment: You can also put both keys in one dictionary: `{ "date" : date, "domain" : domain }`. The implied operation is and.